# Nautilus FTP symbolic links

Tags: nautilus, ftp, symbolic-link

When connecting to an FTP server through Nautilus, symbolic links show as documents. When I attempt to open it, it thinks that the symbolic link is trying to point somewhere on my local machine, and so it says the location doesn't exist. If I open the directory via terminal, `ls` states:

> cannot read symbolic link 'link_name': Function not
>   implemented

For each symbolic link in the directory. I also get this output for any link I try to follow with `cd`.

Is there a resolution for this?

Comment: I think symlinks don't cross filesystems...

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: That is not true. It's a Nautilus issue because FileZilla can navigate to the directories to which the links point just fine.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: However, it is true that hard links don't cross filesystems.

Comment: [Related question on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/500240/13308)